# Как записывать данные в MySQL для конкретного пользователя?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма регистрации. Пользователь регистрируется. Как реализовать выдачу информации из базы данных для конкретного пользователя? 
Вот например для  регистрации есть таблицы с данными пользователя, куда они записываются. 
Далее нужно создать записи, которые записываться в базу для каждого пользователя (например пост). Для выдачи и записи таких данных нужно также таблицу таблицу создавать с логином пользователя или как? Я не совсем правильно понимаю логику. 
Буду благодарен за ссылки, где про это конкретно описано.

Comment: Любую статью откройте по атворизации/регистрации, обычно сейчас записывают в куки уникальные данные для пользователя, тот же id, и по ним берут его данные их базы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Доброй ночи.
Для постов создаёте таблицу с полями

```
id      int      //id поста
title   string   //заголовок поста
text    text     //содержание поста
user_id int   //id пользователя(автора поста)
```

Для записи в эту таблицу, назовём её `posts` будет такой запрос

```
"INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `text`, `user_id`) VALUES ('".$title."','".$text."', '".$user_id."')"
```

Для того, чтобы получить записи конкретного пользователя запрос будет следующим

```
"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id` = $id"
```

Это вкратце, подробней смотрите в документации по [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/), [php](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) и в google)

p.s. Уважаемый **rorry47**, напоминаю, что это не конечный код для использования, а только пример, чтобы Вы увидели как записать и получить данные из базы. Читайте документацию, где всё подробно расписано, как правильно составлять запросы. Я бы этого не писал, но у некоторых пользователей мой ответ вызвал истерику.

Comment: __sql-инъекций__ вы не боитесь, и поэтому всем остальным вы  рекомендуете дырявые методы?

Comment: где Вы увидели рекомендацию? Я показал примеры запросов, добавил, что это всё вкратце и ***порекомендовал(!!!)*** обратиться к официальной документации, как по mysql, так и по php. Расписывать все тонкости обращения к базе, в данном случае, не вижу смысла.

Comment: вот именно - автор вопроса возьмёт ваш дырявый код, и поимеет на нём проблем. И тут дело не в тонкостях, а в элементарной безопасности, которой лично вы пренебрегаете.

Comment: __не хамите__, а лучше воспользуйтесь возможностью отредактировать _(или удалить)_ ваш бесполезный ответ.

Comment: Напишите лучше ответ!

Comment: Благодарю slo-nik за наведенный пример. Я получил что хотел. Да, об *sql-инъекциях* я читал, и в курсе что с этим нужно быть осторожным. Эдуард, я также благодарен и Вам за упоминание о безопасности.